# Hawking Radiation: Mass implications on black holes

Tags: hawking-radiation

Empty space, is indeed not '**empty**.' It is filled with the formation of particle-antiparticle pairs due to Heisenberg uncertainty. Now one of these particles escape into infinity but one of these particles also enter into the black hole. In this case, either the surface area of the black hole should remain constant(if it is balanced) or increase(since there is more mass) but why does it always decrease?

I apologise if this is a basic question, but it was something I've been thinking about for a while and doing research.

---